# Iterate over HasMap in insertion order in <logic:iterate>

Tags: java, struts, hashmap, loops

**I have HasMap object like this:**

```
HashMap<String,String> fileCounter = new HashMap<String,String>();

fileCounter.put("Total Files","15");
fileCounter.put("Total Success Files","10");
fileCounter.put("Total Failed Files","2");
fileCounter.put("Total In Process Files","4");
fileCounter.put("Total Records","100");
fileCounter.put("Total Success Records","80");
fileCounter.put("Total Failed Records","10");
fileCounter.put("Total In Process Records","10");
```

**my iterator logic is this:**

```
<logic:iterate id="mapEntry" name="fileCounter">
  <tr>
    <td><bean:write name="mapEntry" property="key"></td>
    <td><bean:write name="mapEntry" property="value"></td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

**Problem:**

when i perform iteration, map values and keys are shuffled,So all itema are in not printed as given in java code.

can any one help me, How to print this map in as it is in given sequence.

**I want output like this:**

```
Total Files         15
Total Success Files     10
Total Failed Files      2
Total In Process Files  4
Total Records       10
Total Success Records   80
Total Failed Records    10
Total In Process Records    10
```

Comment: Since all you're doing is iterating over a bunch of strings with associated values, and you're inserting them manually, why use a map at all? Just construct strings from the header and data, and put them in a list.

Comment: this is only code where i am facing problem in order of Hasmap, actual code is another.

Comment: and i got the correct answer, now i can done it.

Comment: Using the wrong data structure just seems silly to me, that's all.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think a Map provides a convenient way to pass around name/value data without constricting how it will be presented until necessary.  It'd be a bit early to construct a list of strings in the controller since the entries are going to be output in an HTML table on a JSP page.

Comment: @MattC True, missed that. IMO still the wrong data structure since it's not a map, but a list of pairs.

Comment: @DaveNewton I never really thought about that, but I suppose I agree with that point philosophically.  It's too bad it's probably more work to do it really right.

Comment: @MattC Meh; there's a bunch of pair implementations, and I usually take the few minutes necessary to create little wrapper methods that make it all disappear. Ultimately it's a matter of preference in this case, since the linked map overhead won't matter at all. (If there even is any.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of a regular HashMap.  It iterates in the order that items were inserted.